# Bitmap.createBitmap in android app throwing exception while reloading image

Tags: android, exception, bitmap

I am trying to upload an image from the gallery in the android app. the createBitmap function works fine till I upload just one image, but if I call that function again to reset the image, it throws an exception. Code is below.

```
Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
Bitmap createBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

Bitmap createBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(createBitmap);
```

First call works fine and then I get an exception. Can you please help.
The exception I get is
"An internal error occurred during: "JDI Event Dispatch".
java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Where is stacktrace and decleration of sourceBitmap?

Comment: Can you show more code please

Comment: how do you "reset" the image? make sure you initialize the value of imageView, sourceBitmap and matrix after that reset. We cant tell you more without more code

Comment: I have a button in my app which loads the photo. On press it calls the onActivityResult and fetches the photo. the full code goes like this.So please see my edit